# Why are multiple click events fired when using ngTouch?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mobile-safari, angularjs-ng-touch

I am building a mobile web app with Angular, and I'm trying to incorporate the [ngTouch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch) (angular-touch) module to speed up click events on mobile devices.

Here is the app *without* ngTouch: http://lukasolson.github.io/n-spade-cards/ng-click/

Here is the app *with* ngTouch: http://lukasolson.github.io/n-spade-cards/ng-touch/

I am testing on an iPhone 5 with Safari.

Without the ngTouch module, everything works fine, but there is that annoying 300ms click delay.

However, with the ngTouch module, every time I tap on the screen, the web app thinks that I am tapping twice, ruining the functionality of my app.

Am I including the ngTouch module incorrectly? Why are multiple click events firing?

Comment: Could it be triggering a `click` event and a `touch` event?

Comment: Maybe... But why? As far as I can tell, I'm using it correctly.

Comment: Have you been checking https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6251 lately?

Comment: @coma Yes. Thanks for creating that issue. Now I realize it's not just me.

Answer (score 12):

Source: http://jsfiddle.net/coma/2hWWa/
Test it on your iPhone: http://jsfiddle.net/coma/2hWWa/embedded/result/

```
angular.module('app').directive('myclick', function() {

    return function(scope, element, attrs) {

        element.bind('touchstart click', function(event) {

            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();

            scope.$apply(attrs['myclick']);
        });
    };
});
```

Now you can:

```
<a myclick="aFunction()">click it!</a>
```

And it won't "duplicate" the clicks since "stopPropagation" will prevent the click from happening, only the touchstart will fire.

Just test it and let me know if it's useful.

Btw, If you don't care about zooming then you can avoid the delay with:

http://updates.html5rocks.com/2013/12/300ms-tap-delay-gone-away

I use to add this for "apps".

**UPDATE**

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6251

Comment: Hmm... I actually looked into fastclick a little, but I'd really like to know if this is actually a bug with Angular or if I'm doing something wrong. Your answer provides an alternative, but doesn't show me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Let me change the name to avoid the confusion with https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick . And yes, I think it's a bug, and that's why I just opened a ticket for it https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6251

Comment: @coma: the click event died when I used this technic. What can be the problem?

Comment: @AliSaberi, dunno, try crafting a codepen/jsfiddle to check it out